# Way to select how many rows per page get printed C# and Itext

Tags: c#, gridview, foreach, itext

Here is my code it works great and gets all the rows and creates a barcode label essentially.  However, the user wants an option to select how many print per page and I'm struggling a little with how best to do that?  Is there a way I can do an if statement to say if perPageTextBox = 1 then print 1 row per page?

Here is my code for the printout:

```
 foreach (GridViewRow row in poGridview.Rows)
    {
        String itemNum = row.Cells[0].Text;
        String house = row.Cells[2].Text;
        String staic = row.Cells[4].Text;
        String description = row.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&amp;", ""); 
        String qtOrd = row.Cells[5].Text;
        String serial = row.Cells[12].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
        String stQty = row.Cells[9].Text;
        String deptNum = row.Cells[11].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ; 
        String whBarCode = row.Cells[13].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " ");
        String turnA = row.Cells[19].Text;
        String turnN = row.Cells[20].Text;
        String turnC = row.Cells[21].Text;
        String conversion = row.Cells[7].Text;

        // Warehouse barcode
        Barcode39 whlsc = new Barcode39();
        whlsc.Code = whBarCode.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); 

        // Turn around barcode
        Barcode39 turnAr = new Barcode39();
        //turnAr.Code = (turnA + turnN + turnC);
        turnAr.Code = (poNum + "$I" + itemNum + "$M");

        // Set up lines
        Paragraph itemLine1 = new Paragraph(@"" + itemNum + "              " + house + "               " + description, body);
        Paragraph itemLine2 = new Paragraph(@"          Status -> " + staic + "                                        Ordered:      " + qtOrd + " EA", body);
        Paragraph itemLine3 = new Paragraph(@"STOCKING: " + stQty + " EA               CONVERSION FACTOR: " + conversion + "         ", body);
        Paragraph itemLine4 = new Paragraph(@"Dock: " + "                    Stock:" + "                                      Open:     " + stQty, body);
        Paragraph itemLine5 = new Paragraph(@"Serial #: " + serial , body);
        Paragraph itemLine6 = new Paragraph(@"VND CATALOG: " + serial + "   ", body);
        Paragraph itemLine7 = new Paragraph(@"JOB NUMBER: " + "                           DEPT #: " + deptNum + "               DEFAULT STOCK LOC: ", body);
        Paragraph itemLine8 = new Paragraph(@"                                                                                                                                      ", body);


        // Select command for the comments for each item
        OleDbCommand comtSearch = new OleDbCommand("SELECT CAST(POCOMT.CMNT1 as char(40) ccsid 37) as cmt1, CAST(POCOMT.CMNT2 as char(40) ccsid 37) as cmt2 FROM POCOMT LEFT OUTER JOIN POITEM ON POITEM.ITNBR = POCOMT.ITNBR"
            + $" AND POITEM.ORDNO = POCOMT.ORDNO AND POITEM.HOUSE = POCOMT.HOUSE AND POITEM.LINSQ = POCOMT.LINSQ WHERE POCOMT.ITNBR = '{itemNum}'", cn);

        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(comtSearch);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adp.Fill(dt);
        commentGridview.DataSource = dt;
        commentGridview.DataBind();


        // Add Lines to page
        p.Add(itemLine1);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(itemLine2);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(itemLine3);
        p.Add(new Chunk(turnAr.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));            
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(itemLine4);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        //p.Add(itemLine5);            
        foreach (GridViewRow cmtRow in commentGridview.Rows)
        {
            String cmnt1 = cmtRow.Cells[0].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ;
            String cmnt2 = cmtRow.Cells[1].Text.Replace("&nbsp;", " "); ;
            Paragraph cmt1 = new Paragraph(@"" + cmnt1, body);
            Paragraph cmt2 = new Paragraph(@"" + cmnt2 + " ", body);
            p.Add(cmt1);
            p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
            p.Add(cmt2);
        }

        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(itemLine6);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(itemLine7);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));            
        p.Add(itemLine8);
        p.Add(new Chunk(whlsc.CreateImageWithBarcode(cb, null, null), 0, 0));                     
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));            
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
        p.Add(hr);
        p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));
    }


    p.Add(end);
    p.Add(new Paragraph("\n"));

    pdfDoc.Add(p);

    // Close Document
    pdfDoc.Close();
    Response.Write(pdfDoc);
    Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
    Response.WriteFile(fileTempPath);
    Response.End();
```

Comment: From our last conversation, I understood that you aren't interested in being a customer of iText Software, yet now you say that you have a customer. That can't be correct. When you claim you have a customer, that implies that your customer pays you for the software you write. Having a customer who pays for the software excludes using iText under the AGPL. You should get a commercial license for your use of iText if you have a paying customer. Are you saying that you are using iText illegally? Please clarify.

Comment: This is a small internal program so aren't selling this software by any means.  User should have said employee.  We don't sell any software here all internal use.  Also it said USER not customer.

Comment: If you want to have only *n* rows per page, simply don't create one big table but small tables with *n* rows each and add them to the document always creating a new page in between.

Comment: @mkl that makes sense.. Might have to try that approach instead of the way I did it.

Comment: That's not entirely correct, Bruno. They can have a customer who pays for their software and still be AGPL, as long as they are also AGPL - which means giving their source code to their customers. The best way to do this, is to put the source code in a public repository on GitHub. So, @tstrathman, where can we find your GitHub repository?

Comment: I don't have a customer is the problem.. the post said USER who works for us... internal program not making any money off of it.  Do I need a license for programs that are used internally?